# How to check in an node.js C++ addon, if a promise is resolved

Tags: node.js, v8, node.js-addon, node-nan

### The Task:

I call a callback from C++ that return a v8::Promise (so an async function).
Now I want to find out if the promise was resolved.

For this example here, I want to check from JS if the promise is resolved.
But "just beeing informed in the C++ addon" would be fine.

### The Problem:

I failed to create a persistent Promise object in C++.
I works while I am still in the event loop. But when I get into the event loop again later on, the object is empty.

### The code:

JS test code

```
// create an object in the addon
var OB = require('./build/Debug/objectwraphandle.node')
var obj = new OB.MyObject(42)

// just an async wait function
async function asyncFunc1(y) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        setTimeout(() => resolve('asyncFunc1: DONE'), 2000);
    });
}

// pass the async function as callback to the addon and call it
obj.callAsyncFunction(asyncFunc1);

//  ask the object, it the promise is already resolved.
// this should switch from 1 (Pending) to 0 (Resolved) after 2 seconds
console.log("  resolved? : " + obj.isPromiseResolved());
// but this core-dumps with:
// "FATAL ERROR: v8::Promise::Cast Could not convert to promise"
```

Now the C++ side (by the way - no need to say I am neither C++ nor JS guru)
(original taken from NAN - Native Abstractions for Node.js).
For reproducing, I put the full code here. Important are the functions *CallAsyncFunction* and *IsPromiseResolved*.

```
/*********************************************************************
 * NAN - Native Abstractions for Node.js
 * Copyright (c) 2018 NAN contributors
 * MIT License <https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/LICENSE.md>
 *
 * and now here:  used as test basis by Gerrit Prange
 ********************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <nan.h>

using namespace Nan; 

class MyObject : public ObjectWrap {
 public:
  static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init) {
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> tpl = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
    tpl->SetClassName(Nan::New("MyObject").ToLocalChecked());
    tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

    // these are the two functions in question
    SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "callAsyncFunction", CallAsyncFunction);
    SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "isPromiseResolved", IsPromiseResolved);

    constructor().Reset(Nan::GetFunction(tpl).ToLocalChecked());
    Set(target, Nan::New("MyObject").ToLocalChecked(),
      Nan::GetFunction(tpl).ToLocalChecked());
  }

 private:
  explicit MyObject(double value = 0) : value_(value) {}
  ~MyObject() {}

  // here: the promise is stored as persistent object
  Nan::Persistent<v8::Promise> *persistentPromise;

  static NAN_METHOD(New) {
    if (info.IsConstructCall()) {
      double value = info[0]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : Nan::To<double>(info[0]).FromJust();
      MyObject *obj = new MyObject(value);
      obj->Wrap(info.This());
      info.GetReturnValue().Set(info.This());
    } else {
      const int argc = 1;
      v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] = {info[0]};
      v8::Local<v8::Function> cons = Nan::New(constructor());
      info.GetReturnValue().Set(
          Nan::NewInstance(cons, argc, argv).ToLocalChecked());
    }
  }

  /* we get a callback function (async function),
   * call this callback and get a promise returned
   */
  static NAN_METHOD(CallAsyncFunction) {
    MyObject* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(info.Holder());

    const unsigned argc = 1;
    v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] = { Nan::New("hello world").ToLocalChecked() };

    Callback cb(To<v8::Function>(info[0]).ToLocalChecked());

    // call the callback - and get a Promise
    Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> promiseReturnValue = (*cb)->Call(GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);

    // check if the promise is already resolved. (should not be in this example!)
    v8::Handle<v8::Promise> promiseReturnObject = v8::Handle<v8::Promise>::Cast ( promiseReturnValue.ToLocalChecked() );
    v8::Promise::PromiseState promiseState = promiseReturnObject->State();
    std::cout <<  " state: " << promiseState << std::endl;

    // make the callback persistent
    Nan::Persistent<v8::Promise> persistentPromiseReturnObject(promiseReturnObject);
    obj->persistentPromise = &persistentPromiseReturnObject;
  }

  /* check if the callback is already resolved and return the state
   */
  static NAN_METHOD(IsPromiseResolved) {
    MyObject* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(info.Holder());

    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->GetCurrentContext();

    // get the persistent callback and convert it into a local object
    v8::Local<v8::Object> objectToCheckPromise = Nan::New ( *obj->persistentPromise );
    // THE LINE BELOW IS THE PROBLEM! actually, persiting does not seem to work.
    v8::Local<v8::Promise> promiseObject = v8::Local<v8::Promise>::Cast ( objectToCheckPromise );

    // get the promises state
    v8::Promise::PromiseState promiseState = promiseObject->State();

    // and return the state
    std::cout <<  " in IsPromiseResolved state: " << promiseState << std::endl;
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(promiseState));
  }

  static inline Persistent<v8::Function> & constructor() {
    static Persistent<v8::Function> my_constructor;
    return my_constructor;
  }

  double value_;
};

NODE_MODULE(objectwraphandle, MyObject::Init)
```

The actual error I get is:

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::Promise::Cast Could not convert to promise
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x121a2cc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::Promise::Cast(v8::Value*) [/home/gpr/projects/own/nodejs/jsFromC_NAN_PromiseWait/build/Debug/objectwraphandle.node]
 5: v8::Local<v8::Promise> v8::Local<v8::Promise>::Cast<v8::Object>(v8::Local<v8::Object>) [/home/gpr/projects/own/nodejs/jsFromC_NAN_PromiseWait/build/Debug/objectwraphandle.node]
 6: MyObject::IsPromiseResolved(Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/home/gpr/projects/own/nodejs/jsFromC_NAN_PromiseWait/build/Debug/objectwraphandle.node]
 7: 0x7fb4dd8889dc [/home/gpr/projects/own/nodejs/jsFromC_NAN_PromiseWait/build/Debug/objectwraphandle.node]
 8: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [node]
 9: 0xb9043c [node]
10: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
```

Sorry, this is a long post. (But I wanted to put the code here - if anyone wants to try this out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store Promises in persistent handles. Your code should look something like:

```
class MyObject : public ObjectWrap {
  // ...
private:
  Nan::Persistent<Promise> persistentPromise; // not a pointer!
}

NAN_METHOD(CallAsyncFunction) {
  MyObject* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(info.Holder());
  // ... your function call here
  // returnobj is a Local<Object>
  Local<Promise> p = Local<Promise>::Cast(returnobj);
  obj->persistentPromise.Reset(p);
}

NAN_METHOD(IsPromiseResolved) {
  MyObject* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(info.This());
  Local<Promise> p = obj->persistentPromise.Get(Isolate::GetCurrent());
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(p->State());
}
```

I don't know if there's ever a valid reason to take the address of or dereference a v8 type as an embedder (looking at your callback invocation and how you were setting the persistent handle). There are API methods that do these things safely.

BTW, `Handle` is deprecated; `Local` is its replacement.

Comment: Can you maybe help add callback to see when the promise IS resolved?  This would let me check periodicaly if it has been resolved, but if I just add .Then( context, Local<Function> .. ) I should be able to get those callbacks when it resolves.  My current code throws an error 'TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like v8 Promise is not an object that can be made persistent.

But you can do this:

Add resolve and reject callbacks to the promise so that you get informed when the promise is resolved/rejected.
(I would have liked to add "direct c++ callbacks" instead of having to go via JS, but thats ok for now.)

Or you create a Resolver in your code, which can be made persistent and you can resolve or reject your resolver later in you code.
(Which was another way around my problem for me - maybe looking in that direction also helps you?)